# incorrect anchors in FAQ

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, broken-link

The FAQ page ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)) contains incorrect local links. Now the ids have the form `link-[name]`, and refs have the form `#[name]`. For example, [faq#deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) doesn't point to the right place without JavaScript enabled. In the source code it looks like:

```
<h2 id="link-deletion" ...
<a href="#deletion" ...
```

There should be either `id="deletion"` or `href="#link-deletion"`.

Comment: Thank you. I have NoScript by default. And the such links doesn't work in this case. I have updated the question.

Comment: NoScript? Wow the web must be boring for you!

Comment: Not at all ;)  I suppose thy are smart enough to make good "progressive enhancement" solution that perfectly works in any case  =)

Answer (score 7):

The link isnt broken; StackExchange is just using the feature a little bit differently then normal. They provide the content at the top of the page and in the normal place instead of just jumping to it on the page. Note the link you provided shows the requested content in a highlighted box at the very top of the page and also more near the bottom which is its normal location.